# In a manipulatable graph, display x values of all intersections with one of the lines?

Tags: manipulate, modeling

I'm doing a project about Moore's law, I'm trying to create a graph that which you can manipulate, but I want the x-values of the intersections with one the lines to be displayed; how would I go about doing this?

This is what I have (the first formula is 'real', the rest are placeholders for the sake of having intersections):

```
j0=1980;
Manipulate[LogPlot[{tj0*2^((j - j0)/2), -(b*2^((j - j0)/1.5) - 1000),     
-a*j + c}, {j, 1980, 2000},Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, LabelStyle -> 
{FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 15}, FrameLabel -> {"Year", "Transistor Count"}],
{{tj0, 100, "Transistor Count First Year"}, 100, 200}, {{b, 100, "b-Value"}, 100, 200}, 
{{a, 100, "a-Value"}, 80,  120}, {{c, 250000, "c-Value"}, 250000, 300000}]
```

[image]

What I would like is something like this:

```
Manipulate[ If[(-M + M p + Ls z - Ls p z)/(-1 + z) <= M, Plot[{If[G <= M, (-G + M + G z - Ls z)/z], If[(-M + M p + Ls z - Ls p z)/(-1 + z) <= M, Exp[((1 - p)*Log[G] - p*Log[((M p - Ls p z)/z)] - (1 - p)* Log[((-M + M p + Ls z - Ls p z)/(-1 + z))])/-p]]}, {G, 0, 2000}, AxesLabel -> {" SubscriptBox[\"W\", \"G\"] ", " SubscriptBox[\"W\", \"B\"] "}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2500}, {0, 2500}}, AxesStyle -> Directive[Bold], LabelStyle -> Bold, Epilog -> {Thick, Dashed, Line[{{(-M + M p + Ls z - Ls p z)/(-1 + z), 0}, {(-M + M p + Ls z - Ls p z)/(-1 + z), (M p - Ls p z)/ z}}]}, Prolog -> {Thick, Black, Line[{{0, 0}, {2500, 2500}}]}, PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}, {Thick, Purple}}, PlotLabel -> "Optimal Insurance Contract"], Plot[{If[G <= M, (-G + M + G z - Ls z)/z], G}, {G, 0, 2500}, AxesStyle -> Directive[Bold], AxesLabel -> {" SubscriptBox[\"W\", \"G\"] ", " SubscriptBox[\"W\", \"B\"] "}, PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}, {Thick, Black}}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2500}, {0, 2500}}, AxesStyle -> Directive[Bold], Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[{M, M - Ls}]}, PlotLabel -> "Optimal Insurance Contract", LabelStyle -> Bold]], {{p, .5, "Probability of Bad State"}, .1, .9}, {{M, 1000, "Original Wealth"}, 500, 1250}, {{z, .52, "Insurance Premium"}, .3, .9}, {{Ls, 200, "Loss"}, 50, 900}, Text[Style[ "Wealth in the Good State = " Dynamic[ If[(-M + M p + Ls z - Ls p z)/(-1 + z) <= M, Dynamic[(-M + M p + Ls z - Ls p z)/(-1 + z)], M]], 12, "Label"]], Text[Style[ "Wealth in the Bad State = " Dynamic[ If[(-M + M p + Ls z - Ls p z)/(-1 + z) <= M, Dynamic[(M p - Ls p z)/z], M - Ls]], 12, "Label"]], Text[Style[ "Premium = " Dynamic[ If[(-M + M p + Ls z - Ls p z)/(-1 + z) <= M, Dynamic[M - (-M + M p + Ls z - Ls p z)/(-1 + z)], 0]], 12, "Label"]]]
```

[image]

I'd like thick dashed lines to go down to the x-axes from the intersections of any of the lines with the first blue line and the x (or j value here) to be displayed like in the second example.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
j0 = 1980;

Manipulate[
 f1[j_] := tj0 2^((j - j0)/2);
 f2[j_] := -(b 2^((j - j0)/1.5) - 1000);
 f3[j_] := -a j + c;
 j12 := j /. FindRoot[f1[j] == f2[j], {j, 1980}];
 j13 := j /. FindRoot[f1[j] == f3[j], {j, 1980}];
 LogPlot[{f1[j], f2[j], f3[j]}, {j, 1980, 2000},
  Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {.1, 10^6}, 
  LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 15}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Year", "Transistor Count"},
  Epilog -> {Dashed,
    Line[{{j12, -10}, {j12, Log@f1[j12]}}],
    Line[{{j13, -10}, {j13, Log@f1[j13]}}]},
  PlotLabel -> Row[{"Critical years: ", j12, " and ", j13 }]
  ],
 {{tj0, 100, "Transistor Count First Year"}, 100, 200},
 {{b, 100, "b-Value"}, 100, 200},
 {{a, 100, "a-Value"}, 80, 120},
 {{c, 250000, "c-Value"}, 250000, 300000}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Many thanks, but is there any way to dynamically display the x (or j here) values of those intersections as well?

Comment: @John. Yes, see edit above. You can also add this data to inside the plot. I am less familiar with the necessary commands but I am sure the Help can help you. Basically you can reuse any local variable in the plot layout.